# how to set interval in lambda start job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have lambda that stops a running job and start a different glue job. It goes like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('glue')
    body = json.loads(event['body'])            
    job_id_to_stop = body['job_id_to_stop']     
    job_to_start_argument = body['job_to_start_argument'] 
    client.batch_stop_job_run(                              #STOP JOB RUN
            JobName='job-to-stop',    
            JobRunIds=[
                    job_id_to_stop                 
                ]
    )
    
    client.start_job_run(                                   #START JOB RUN
            JobName = 'job-to-start',    
            Arguments = {
                '--job_to_start_argument':  job_to_start_argument                       
            }
        )
    return  {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "Success"
    }
```

Now I know that lambda dies after running and I don't need it to run indefinitely. However, I want to add a delay between stop_job_run and start_job_run. So after stopping the first glue job, I want lambda to wait at least 5 seconds before running the start_job_run. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `time.sleep(5)` in between the calls and ensure the lambda has a timeout that is large enough to submit both requests and wait for 5s, e.g. have the timeout be 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an explicit sleep() within a Lambda function with great caution: the billing model for Lambda is based on execution time, and deliberately pausing execution for N seconds would unnecessarily increase the cost.

In this scenario, I would instead use a Step Function, orchestrating multiple Lambdas to stop/start the respective jobs (if I recall correctly you can also manage Glue jobs directly in Step Functions, but I don't know if it fits your use case).
This would also provide more room for customization, configuration, and reuse.

Comment: Sleeping for 5s in a lambda with probably only 128MB cost around 1/1000 of a single cent. Setting up anything more complicated than lambda is a million times more expensive.

Comment: Actually the step function itself is probably already more expensive

Comment: Using sleep(5) is indeed faster and more cost-effective in a basic scenario. However, I'm referring to a long-term scenario and a solution that, as mentioned, offers greater customization and reusability.
If the use case remains consistent and singular, managing it with a Lambda using sleep() is certainly the best choice.